# CosmosDB with SQL API - incremental order of the "_rid" field

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using cosmos DB with my spring boot application, and looking for a way to assign sequential id for every new entry into the collection.

There's a similar query here , which suggests the use of "_rid":
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/38106916-new-cosmosdb-sql-api-built-in-function-newid-b

I also observed that when i added new items in a particular collection, every item has the following _rids :-

"_rid": "qslAAL+OyU8**D**AAAAAAAAAA=="

"_rid": "qslAAL+OyU8**E**AAAAAAAAAA=="

"_rid": "qslAAL+OyU8**F**AAAAAAAAAA=="

And the above pattern goes on for every item in the order of insertion. I have tested this only for a few records though.

I am unable to find any documentation on this, as to what happens if there are a lot many more records , in the order of thousands ?!

If any kind soul could explain the mechanism/pattern behind this / point to some documentation then that would be really helpful !!

Thanks!

EDIT 1: Adding use case details :-
Maintaining a record of entries in order of insertion. Every entry gets an integer number as it's sequence number. This sequence for me is important. A new record can 'override' the old record using the sequence number and that's the reason i need the unique id.  I cannot use Guid or uuid because i need to display the number on UI, and that's how the user will know which record to override.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_rid` is a ResourceId, or unique resource identifier. It is part of the System Properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/documents

[image: What is _rid]

Not something that you should rely your logic on because there is no behavior contract (nothing that says it increments or how).

Comment: Thanks Matias. I also observed that _rid increments even if save attempt fails. Is there a way to configure a trigger that gives an incremented counter only on successful save ?

Comment: If what you want is an autoincrement `id`, that is not an available feature as far as I know. You can use [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#triggers) but I'm not sure the atomicity (what if two concurrent requests execute the same trigger to obtain a new incremental value).

Comment: If i can get a way to make the trigger atomic, and increment counter only on a successful save, that would help tremendously !

Comment: I see this Azure documentation which kinda relates in part the issue; maybe i can configure something? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency

Comment: The problem is that if you are concurrently (from multiple concurrent requests) executing the Trigger, there is nothing that will assure you you are getting unique values. That's why any id generation logic should be on the application side.

Comment: Thanks Matias, i understand. But since i'm using a microstrategy architecture, i dont hav the option of storing state in my application, as i can have multiple instances running at the same time. Is there a way i can write stored procedure in cosmos with a lock ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, there are no locks that can prevent a StoredProcedure to be executed concurrently, it would need to be the app layer locking and making sure no two threads go through it concurrently, but on a microservice architecture, that doens't seem possible. Why cannot you use Guids? That would be random enough to avoid any issues.

Comment: I need every new record to get a sequential integer number. So i cannot have guids. I was thinking about something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260581/locking-and-concurrent-executions-of-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Sadly that doesn't exist in Cosmos DB sprocs as far as I know

Comment: Thanks Matias, I'll need an official answer though. Im good if i can consider your answer as one, or if there is a support channel where i can raise this query pls do let me know ..

Answer (score 1):

_rid is for internal use. The latest spring data cosmos does not auto generate the value for ID field. Previously the API was capable of generating a unique value for ID field, but even then it was was not a sequential increment.

Will will have to generate the sequentially incremented ID or random ID from the client side.

If you want to implement this correctly be in single instance or multiple instances of the client, you will have to include another component to keep the counter. Check out "Atomic Long" from Apache Curator/Zookeeper or Apache ignite.

UPDATE:
You could also consider Twitter snowflake.

Comment: how can we do that in a microservice - cloud environment where we can have multiple instances of the application running simultaneously ?

Comment: What is your need for sequentially incremented id?

Comment: maintaining a record of entries in order of insertion. new entry can override old entry vie the "id". so they need to be unique and sequential.

Comment: is there a way to add something like a trigger in cosmosDB - sql api , which will give an incremented counter only on successful save ? I can see that _rid increments even on failed save attempts.

Comment: No. You will have to use a external service to do that.

Comment: Hi Ravi - what about this  ? :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency

Comment: @Jcoder are you suggesting using _etag value as a sequential id?

Comment: no.  i am rather looking for a stored procedure with a locking mechanism .. something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260581/locking-and-concurrent-executions-of-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @Jcoder can you explain the use case you are trying to implement? The "What" part!

Comment: maintaining a record of entries in order of insertion. every entry gets an integer number as it's sequence number. This sequence for me is important. A new record can 'override' the old record using the sequence number and that's the reason i need the unique id.  I cannot use Guid or uuid because i need to display the number on UI, and that's how im gonne know which one to override. Use case added in question.